# HDIV changable hidden field

Tags: hdiv

I have a hidden field in my page which is manipulated by javascript. HDIV doesn't like it, and gives a invalid parameter value. How can I configure HDIV to understand that the javascript might change the value, and avoid the unauthorized access problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the default HDIV verify the integrity of all non editable (read only) paramaters, such as hidden fields. if you want to deactivate this behaviour for one parameter within a url you can define an exclusion for that. For instance, this is the XML configuration for a similar example:

```
<hdiv:config>
  <hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
    <hdiv:mapping url="/section/.*" parameters="paramName"/>
  </hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
</hdiv:config>
```

See: http://www.hdiv.org/hdiv-documentation-single/doc.html#advancedConfiguration-startparameters